# Value conversion integer position to doubling sequence

Tags: java, android, math

I have a simple slider (SeekBar) with the fixed range [0, 8]

When I change the value of this slider I want to convert these values as follows

`[0, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]`

It's late and I've confused myself with the maths - what's the simplest way to do this? I convinced myself there should be a simple way to do it using powers ( Math.pow() ) but failed a number of times

*edit* Just thought I'd add - I know how to get the progress updates using an OnSeekBarChangeListener it's just the actual conversion algorithm I'm struggling with

Comment: You are on the right track, but the problem is indeed with 0, since something powered to 0 is 1. Since 32 is 2^5, you can use `Math.pow(2, value-3)`, with exception when the value is 0, return 0.

Comment: Yes, that was the closest I got, but it still seems like a hack if I'm having to manually handle one value as I get 0.125 each time I go back to position zero

Comment: what's your split criterion ? see your example,[0,8] then you divide it to 0,Math.pow(2.0,i) where i is a integer range from [-2,5].give me your criterion .

Comment: Sorry, you lost me at divide it to 0

Comment: That's the only formula if using `Math.pow()`. I don't think it's a hack since it's impossible to use `Math.pow()` to get 0 with base 2. Alternatively, just create a direct mapping with `double` array. `double[] result = {0, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32};` and use the value as the index :p

Comment: I tried so many 'formulas' (practically random guesses) and settled on "double val = ((progress > 0)? Math.pow(2, progress-3) : 0)" (then opened this question), but it feels hacky, put your comments as an answer and if nobody has a perfect answer I'll accept yours later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *simplest* way to accomplish it is to reference an array you have assigned somewhere in your code (as comments/other users have pointed out):

```
// somewhere in your code (possibly static?)
double[] _result = { 0, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 };

// then your function
public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
{
    // would need to handle if progress is ever > _result.max
    System.out.format("%f%n", _result[progress]);
}
```

However, if you want the *mathematical* way to do it (based on the inputs/outputs you've specified), you'll need to implement some bit shifting:

```
public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
{
    // get the 'max' of our bar
    double max = (double)seekBar.getMax(); // 8
    // get the 'max' of our 'array' values, this could be a const value
    // or some other formula (like max * 4f)
    double pmax = 32;
    // get our 'mask' by shifting '1' left 'progress' times, then divide by 2
    // to get the divisor to our other formula
    double p = (double)(1 << progress) / 2; 
    // if progress == 0, then just return 0 (since that's our min)
    double val = ((progress == 0) ? 0 : (max / (pmax / p)));

    // the 'one-liner': 
    // ((double)seekBar.getMax()) / (pmax / ((double)(1 << progress) / 2)))

    System.out.format("%f%n", val);
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: This is interesting, but again its not as maintainable as the powers method because it requires you to either find or change pmax whenever max changes - ie if theres now 9 values, max would be 64 and max*4f wouldnt work

Comment: yeah, I agree that it's not as maintainable :) more trying to show that it could be possible through a formula (admittedly not the simplest approach though).